# Probability of flush given that you observe 4 diamonds out of 5 cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, poker

I came across this probability problem.

> In a Texas Hold’em game, you are dealt 2 cards in your hands and the 3 flop cards are shown. You observe 4 diamonds out of the 5 cards. What are your chances of getting a flush?

Given that I see 4 diamonds already, isn't the probability just ${{13 - 4}\over{52 - 4}} = {3\over{16}}$? What am I missing?

**Update:** So in response to the comments, then the answer should simply be $1 - \left({{38}\over{47}}\right)\left({{37}\over{46}}\right) = {{378}\over{1081}}$?

Comment: No, since there will be $2$ more cards dealt. Not only one.

Comment: In Texax Hold 'Em, there should be two more cards to come.  All you need is for at least one of these to be a diamond.  As usual, it's easier to compute the probability that *neither* of the two is a diamond.

Comment: Also, it would be $\frac{13-4}{52-4} = \frac3{16}$ in the simple case.

Comment: The answer in your update looks right and you should post that as an answer.